# Colocar texto al final de una pagina

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Buen dia, usando el plugin jspdf, el codigo que dejaré coloca un contador de pagina al generar el pdf en la parte inferior derecha quedando 1/2 para la primera pagina, 2/2 para la segunda, suponiendo que sean 2 paginas.

Lo que necesito es colocar un texto "ULTIMA PAGINA" en la misma posicion pero solamente en la ultima pagina

alguna idea?

Aqui el codigo:

```
pdf.setFontSize(9);
var pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
for(i = 0; i < pageCount; i++){
   pdf.setPage(i);
   pdf.text(190,285, pdf.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber + "/" + pageCount);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un código como éste te debería poder valer:

```
pdf.setFontSize(9);
var pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages(); // pageCount es el nº de páginas
for(i = 0; i < pageCount; i++){ // código que se repite para cada página (bucle)
   var currentPage = pdf.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber; // página actual
   pdf.setPage(i);
   if (currentPage  < pageCount) { // condiciona, si el nº de página actual es menor que el nº de páginas
      pdf.text(190,285, "Página " + currentPage + " de " + pageCount); // escribir 'Página "nº de pagina actual" de "nº de páginas"'
   } else { // en caso contrario
      pdf.text(190,285, "ÚLTIMA PÁGINA"); // escribir 'ÚLTIMA PÁGINA'
   }
}
```

Básicamente, lo que haces es guardar el número de página actual en la variable *currentPage* (para no llamar dos veces al método en cada iteración del for) y luego comprobar si esa página es menor que la última (*pageCount*). Si es menor, muestra tu código anterior, y en caso contrario (currentPage sería igual que pageCount y estarías en la última página) se mostrar el texto que deseas "ÚLTIMA PÁGINA".

Comment: Recuerda que una explicación de tu código mejora la aceptación del mismo, pues solo responder con scripts se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Gracias. Edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Si haces ```if (i = (pageCount -1))``` te ahorras una linea, realmente no hace falta declarar la nueva variable

Comment: Tienes razón en que se puede ahorrar una línea. Supongo que querrías decir ```if (i == (pageCount - 1))```, ¿no?
De todas formas, la creación de la variable lo puse por claridad del código.

Comment: Tecnicamente se podría hacer todo en una linea, pero es más visual como lo ha hecho, y si funciona bien, no es necesario liarse la cabeza pensando como ahorrar espacio (Sobre todo a personas nuevas en stack overflow)